# Why would mvn clean install and eclipse differ in junit tests they run?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have differences between Junit tests when I run them inside Eclipse and when they are run by maven surefire pluging doing an `mvn clean install` from a terminal

On one project, when I right click on `src/test/java` in Eclipse,Junit tells me there are 137 tests run. Doing `mvn clean install` gives me only 119. On this one, it seems that case in test name might be a possible explanation some of tests do not start with lower case and this makes surefire ignore them but are there any other possible explanation?

On a second project, I have a more annoying problem : en entire test package is not run by `mvn clean install`. I have 2 packages under `src/test/java` : `com.project` and `com.project.services`. Test classes under `com.project`are run correctly by surefire, not the ones under `com.project.services`.

The only specificity I can see is classes under `com.project.services` have several level of inheritance :

```
public class ActualTestsCasesA extends GenericTestSituationA {}

public class GenericTestSituationA extends ServicesAbstractTests {}

public abstract ServicesAbstractTests extends ProjectAbstractTests {}
```

`ActualTestsCasesA`, `GenericTestSituationA` and `ServicesAbstractTests` are all under `com.project.services` test package. ProjectAbstractTests stays in an other maven project.

Here is the dependency to surefire plugin in my pom.wml :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: does `mvn help:effective-pom` return different results when run in each environment?

Comment: Looking at eclipse effective pom tab on the pom.xml, the surefire-plugin part is the same on both sides.

Comment: Check the names of your unit tests. Are you following the naming convention of unit tests like `*Test.java*`?

Comment: you might just use the wrong naming for the classes. the surefire plugin includes test classes based on the filename: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes - maybe eclipse is a bit smarter and is scanning for @Test annotation. So renaming the tests to match the surefire defaults or configuring its includes to match the names your are using should work.

Comment: @wemu  : that's it, thanks problem was in the names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, Surefire has a specific naming convention when running tests. You can, however, configure additional naminig conventions to match your own project's test filenames. This is helpful for legacy tests that may not have been adhering to the Maven standard, or for a large suite of test classes you would rather not refactor.

Check out the Surefire documentation for details: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

In your case, you could configure Surefire to include test classes with additional patterns like so:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
            <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests*.*</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSituation*.*</include>
            </includes>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Eclipse, however, isn't bound by such restrictions. Instead, it relies on the existence of the junit4 library to run tests, and allows jUnit itself to determine if a class is considered a runnable test or not. See the [Eclipse Mars docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm) for a little more info.